# How can I make bend in google maps polyline?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to make a bend in `Google maps` **polyline**. 
Sample Example is [here](http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/embedded-polyline.jpg)

I want to make a line over the railway and not a straight line.
Is it feasible?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible.  You need the coordinates that define the "bend" in the polyline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, you only have to look at the documentation of google maps, there are many examples, you just have to replace the latitude and longitude [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?hl=es)